# memcpy equivalent for skipping x bytes while copying (not just initial x bytes)?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I'm looking for an existing function similar to memcpy that can be told to copy *x* bytes and then skip *y* bytes, repeating until a specified amount has been copied.

Imagine a buffer with data: `AABAAB` (I've used characters, but the data I'm manipulating is not string data).

When applied to this buffer and told to copy 2 bytes and skip 1 byte, the destination buffer would contain: `AAAA`.

I haven't found anything looking through STL and Boost, but am hoping there's something in either that I've missed.

Or perhaps there's a clever (and not nasty) way of using more common functions to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I'm no Boost user, but wouldn't this be trivial to write using `memcpy()` in a loop? Are you no longer allowed to write new code in modern C++? :)

Comment: maybe you can use `std::copy_if`

Comment: I'm hoping to be able to take advantage of an optimised, tested function - which I don't really have time to implement... if it comes to it, though, that is what I'll have to do.

Comment: Are you talking about raw data or string manipulations. Memcpy() should work good for raw data. However, for strings etc you can use std::transform(), where you can define the behavior in lambda functions

Comment: @Dkg Raw data - I'll update my question.

Comment: @appleapple Thanks, I'm looking into copy_if now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a direct equivalent of memcpy for doing what I wanted. Boost does seem to often some useful helper functions, but I ended up implementing a simple looping function to do the job as it seemed the most simple & appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into [`boost::adaptors::strided`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/strided.html).

You'd probably write something like this:

```
boost::copy(boost::make_iterator_range(in, in+size) | boost::adaptors::strided(2), out);
```

While this produces lots of assembly, it seems to also be perfectly inlineable by the compiler: [compiler explorer example](https://godbolt.org/g/R3UFHc).

To remove every nth element you could also resort to [`boost::adaptors::filtered`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html) with a predicate that disallows every nth element (`strided` does the opposite and *keeps* every nth one):

```
char const* input = "AABAAB";

unsigned counter{};
auto pred = [&counter](auto const&){ return ++counter % 3; };
boost::copy(boost::make_iterator_range(input, input+strlen(input)) | boost::adaptors::filtered(pred),
            std::ostream_iterator<char>(cout));
```

[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xKEI6wEh0ZE2o6OC);

Comment: Thanks this looks promising - am I correct in supposing that I'd have to have my data stored in a STL container (like vector) rather than a plain array?

Comment: I think it should work with any range made from iterator pair. I'll update with an example.

Comment: @grae22 updated, though I'm no longer sure if this is the answer to your problem or the best way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll have to implement my own function - these methods you've suggested look like they could do the job nicely, so I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: thanks - this was an interesting exercise in getting more familiar with boost, but ultimately I ended up implementing my own function with a simple looping implementation.